# Can I freeze cranberry sauce?

Tags: sauce, freezing

I made delicious cranberry sauce with fresh berries, sugar and brandy.  Can I freeze it?

Comment: One of the lazy (and energy saving) ways I employ to mush up vegetables and fruits is by freezing them first. Freezing breaks down their fibres.

Comment: Be aware that alcohol has a lower freezing point than water, so if you end up not freezing it completely, then the ice will have a lower percentage of alcohol than the unfrozen portion.

Answer (score 1):

It will certainly be safe to eat if you freeze it, but cranberry pectin is not freeze stable, so you will probably get a more watery product when it is thawed out.

Comment: You might be able to avoid this (known as syneresis) somewhat with guar gum, locust bean gum or xanthan gum

Comment: Its cranberry sauce, one of the most pectin rich natural fruits.  There is something vaguely offputting about entertaining putting in different gums or thickeners.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will be fine to freeze. I've never had any problems in the past