# Can I make cranberry sauce from frozen cranberries and re-freeze it?

Tags: freezing

I have cranberries which were fresh, and then accidentally placed in the freezer. 
They are now frozen. Can I make cranberry sauce with them and then freeze that until Christmas?

Comment: see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40770/can-i-freeze-cranberry-sauce?rq=1 - almost a duplicate, since I think there is no difference between the berries having been frozen previouslz or not.

Comment: As they told me during my training at food factory: everything can be frozen if you boil it beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

I see no reason otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but there's probably no reason to refreeze it rather than just refrigerate it.  It can last a month without any problem, and refreezing tends not to be good for either texture or conservation, no matter what the food involved.